# how to run JavaScript code when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

There is a button that passes value to another input field. but now I want to pass value if checkbox is checked.

```js
const copy = (id) => {
  var value = document.getElementById("col" + id + "-input").value
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("col" + id + "-input")
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    list[i].value = value
}

document.getElementById("col1-button").addEventListener("click", () => copy(1))
```

```html
<a type="button" id="col1-button">OK</a>
```

Comment: Anchors don't have types

Answer (score 0):

1. `a` does not have a type.
2. Pass the number in a data-attribute then you can reuse the script for more than one button

I guessed the HTML. Next time post a complete example please

```js
const copy = e => {
  const tgt = e.target; 
  if (tgt.type !=="checkbox" || !tgt.checked) return;
  const id = e.target.dataset.id;
  var value = document.getElementById("col" + id + "-input").value
  document.querySelectorAll(".col" + id + "-input").forEach(inp => inp.value = value);
};

document.getElementById("col1-button").addEventListener("click",copy)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="col1-input" />
<input type="text" class="col1-input" />
<input type="text" class="col1-input" />
<input type="text" class="col1-input" />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="col1-button" data-id="1" />OK</label>
```

Comment: yes i want to trigger this with checkbox instead of button

Comment: See updated script